# Rails 4: Helper method for Devise mailer views throws undefined method exception sometimes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, actionmailer

In order to use a custom helper method in the mailers, I had to define a module and created a method as follows,

```
# app/helpers/mailer_helper.rb
module MailerHelper
  def format_email_template
    # body..
  end
end
```

And then I had to tell `Devise` to use this helper module. After some research, I found one solution that it should be mentioned as follows in the `config/initializers/devise.rb` file,

```
# config/initializers/devise.rb
# Already exists
Devise.setup do |config|
  # Some configuration settings
end

# I added this
# If I don't add this, helper methods are not at all available in the mailer views
Devise::Mailer.class_eval do
  helper :mailer
end
```

This works fine and I could use a helper method in the `devise` mailer views.

But the problem is that it sometimes throws an error `Undefined method :format_email_template for view class`. Then I had to restart my local server to make it work. This happens very frequently.

Why this is happening in development server (WEBrick)?

Note:- This works find in production box. But I am bit worried if it could appear in production also.

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

```
Undefined method :format_email_templage for view class
```

Maybe the problem is your typo (format_email_**templage**)? Please check it again in your source code!

Comment: Yes its a typo! I have modified it in my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
helper :mailer
```

in your custom mailer class as suggested here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-custom-mailer